# Display object offset from mouse position during pressmove

Tags: createjs

I have constructed a volume slider in flash CC and published to createjs but when I drag the Nob inside the slider the Nob position is offset from the mouse position by the Slider.x position. I have looked at all of the examples on this site and I believe that this can be fixed by using either localToGlobal or globalToLocal but so far I have not been able to work out how to do this.

My project is using the following library "http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.1.min.js" and the java script code to control the slider is as follows

```
this.Slider.Nob.addEventListener("pressmove",VolumeDrag);
function VolumeDrag(event){
event.currentTarget.x = Math.min(230, Math.max(0, event.stageX));
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try swapping out `stageX` with `localX`.

Comment: Tried that already, it reversed to offset logarithmically, but your comment did get me thinking that localToGlobal was not the answer so I wrote this bit of code that does work. this.Slider_mc.Nob_mc.addEventListener("pressmove",VolumeDrag2);
  function VolumeDrag2(event){
          var NobPos = (event.stageX - 115);
       event.currentTarget.x = Math.min(230, Math.max(0, NobPos));
      } until that is you dynamically resize the stage.